# Generalized Mean Value Theorem for lebesgue integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ a measurable set with finite measure and let $f \in L^1(\Omega)$. It's true that holds a "mean value theorem" in this case? That is, it's possible to find $c=c(f)>0$ such that:

$$
\int_{\Omega} f dx = c(f)\mu(\Omega)?
$$

Actually, for my purposes, i need only of a estimative of the form

$$
\int_{\Omega} f dx \le c(f)\mu(\Omega)
$$

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Such an estimate does not necessarily make sense for integrable functions, which are only defined almost everywhere.

Comment: if i change $f(a)$ by $||f||_1$?

Comment: the only thing I wanted was an estimate of the type

$\int_{\Omega} f dx \le c(f) \mu(\Omega)$

Comment: At the moment this seems kind of trivial or unclear because a constant that depends on the function $f$ is allowed to depend on the domain of $f$ and so we can have $c(f)\mu(\Omega) = \|f\|_{L^1(\Omega)}$, which makes it trivial.

Comment: Someone beat me to it: as stated this is just silly; _define_ $c(f)=\int f/\mu(\Omega)$. It must be that whether you know it or not you really need the mapping $f\mapsto c(f)$  to have some property or other...